# Can we rename soap response with multiple namespace on spring-boot application?

Tags: soap, spring-boot

I have soap response which having multiple namespace as below,

xmlns:**SOAP-ENV**="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:**ns2**="http://spring.io/guides/gs-producing-web-service"

but I want change these namespace as S and ns5, and produce same xml as response

xmlns:**S**="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"

xmlns:**ns5**="http://spring.io/guides/gs-producing-web-service"

Comment: these are namespace names. It does not matter what name they have as long as internal tags have correct namespaces associated to them. But still if you want to change it, you can do it in an interceptor. For example,  by implementing `ClientInterceptor` (if you are writing client) or `SoapEndpointInterceptor` (if you are writing the server).

Comment: Thanks Rajkishan for your help. Using Interceptor I am able to produce desired namespace but it will be good if we able to modified using  package-info.java file as below,

Comment: e.g.  @javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(namespace = "http://www.ech.ch/xmlns/eCH-0007/3", elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED, xmlns = {
    @javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNs(namespaceURI = "http://www.ech.ch/xmlns/eCH-0007/3", prefix = "eCH-0007")
})
package ch.ech.ech0007.v3;

Comment: I would suggest using interceptor. So that you don't need to modify auto generated codes.

Comment: Thanks  @Rajkishan